# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1

Tags: java, массивы, индексы

У меня возникла ошибка в программе на Java.

Вот сама ошибка:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1

В чем причина ?

Вот сам код:

```
package javaapplication15;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication15 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        
        System.out.println("Введите колличество n слов -");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        String[] str = new String[n];
        String b;
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            b= sc.nextLine();
            str[i] = b;
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `<`, а не  `<=`.
Иначе вы обращаетесь к элементу, которого нет, т.к. индексация массива начинается с нуля. Ваш цикл должен последний раз выполниться для `i = n - 1`